# Can we take any physical quantity as a generalized co-ordinate in Lagrangian function?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, constrained-dynamics

Lagrangian function is a function of generalized co-ordinates $q_1,q_2,....$ & possibly of time $t$.

i.e.  $L=L(q_1,q_2,....;t)$

Consider a simple pendulum.

Can I take
$q_1$ = kinetic energy of pendulum
$q_2$ = angular momentum of pendulum
as generalized co-ordinates of the motion of pendulum?
Here both are functions of time. And no explicit dependence of $L$ on time $t$.

If answer to above question is yes, then what will be the functional form of this particular Lagrangian?

Comment: Simple pendulum has one generalized coordinate, you can take  x or y or $\theta$ to be the generalized coordinate

Answer (score 0):

Note that [generalized coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_coordinates) $(q^1, \ldots,q^n)$ (together with time $t$) should provide full information about the positions $({\bf r}_1, \ldots,{\bf r}_N)$ of the system (without having to solve the EOMs).

*Example.* If we consider the [simple pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum), then the angle $\theta$ is a generalized coordinate. But the angular velocity $\dot{\theta}$, the angular momentum $L=I\dot{\theta}$, and the kinetic energy $K=\frac{1}{2}I \dot{\theta}^2$ are not (since they provide information about velocity rather than position).